# Ubuntu 23.04 problemas al instalar impresora Epson L1250

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencias, impresora, epson

Buenas tardes a todos los amigos de la comunidad, resulta que compre una impresora Epson L1250, para instalar tengo que tener los driver, asi que en la pagina oficial de epson encontre el driver, Pagina:
 https://www.epson.com.sg/Ink-Tank-Printers/L-Series/Epson-L1250/s/SPT_C11CJ71503?review-filter=Linux
pagina de descarga:
http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule
la cual me pide instalar Ubuntu: **# apt install lsb**, desde ahi ya viene el problema y no se como proceder ya que me dice que falta dependencias, he instalado lsb,pero lo reconoce, espero su pronta ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Podrías colocar el comando (o serie de comandos) que estás usando y la salida (**como texto**, no como imagen) en la pregunta, por favor?

Answer (score 1):

aquí les dejo la solución, como les comente estaba intentando instalar el paquete lsb, pero al instalar me salia un mensaje: "no existe lbs (o algo asi)",no lo encontraba, así que buscando por internet encontré un video, este es el link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoMskA2yTeg

Aquí me indica que como prioridad instalara este archivo:
lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb

este archivo estaba en los paquetes de Debian pero lo sacaron, pero aca dejo el link de descarga:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/lx3w8v8n4uvgf7y/lsb-compat_9.20161125_amd64.deb/file

una vez instalado, debes de instalar el driver que te entrega en la pagina de Epson, la cuales tienen este nombre:
epson-inkjet-printer-202101w_1.0.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb 
  epson-printer-utility_1.1.1-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
esto me funcionó y ahora imprimo tranquilamente, saludos a todos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).